# How to track and find the source code of changes made in Dev Tools?

Tags: css, .net, devtools

[image: DevToolsImage]

So I am a very new developer (less than a month) with no formal education and I am working on bugfixes with a WebApp (.NET Framework). I was asked to remove a button from one of graphs as it was redundant. So I open dev tools and inspect the element. Go to the html (picture below) and "add" a (style = "Display:none") attribute to the HTML and it does the job exactly as I want it! yay!

Now I need to change the source code... but For the life of me I cannot find anything related to this. I search for the class, ID, and various other attributes in VStudio but nothing. I assume this is because the HTML and/or CSS is spawned from a JS file.

How do I now trace the source code responsible for this? And in general, how does one translate a change made on dev tools to the real code? We use w2ui, plotly, and bootstrap.

I have already tried the sources page on dev tools but the file it referes to is basically empty.

Sorry if this is phrased poorly or a repost, I am really new to all of this but LOVE every second of it.

[image: DevToolsImage]

[image: DevToolsImage]

Comment: I added a few pictures but they seem to have dissipated. sorry

Comment: i understand you are new but, this wont help us much. some code samples or snippets might help. in the current form, the question is of no use.

Comment: @Jay Hi. I have uploaded some images regarding the matter. It says "constructed stylesheet" instead of a location. Also, the JS file is line 100 lines in the source code but 800 on dev tools. I presume this is the doing of the frameworks we use? how do I track how the 100 lines have expanded? I tried searching the ID of the button but nothing is returned

Comment: i have made your images display with an edit. hope it shows up soon. now, about the actual issue, the question is looking good now. wait for others to help you out. i was mainly helping you make the question look proper.

Comment: @Jay I see. Thanks! I appreciate the help. :) have a great weekend

Comment: Does the button you're trying to remove have a unique id or CSS class that's not used on other elements? 

I know it's not exactly what you were wanting to do, but if it does, instead of removing the button you could add some CSS targeting the id or class and set it's display property like you did inline using Dev Tools and hide it.